gcc can find the library, but g++ cannot, when it is spcified -l option
I am now implementing a linux applicaiton using pciutils library. I built the repository to generate header files and static library named libpci.a by the command make PREFIX=./local install-lib, as the README explains.
After the building for library, I tried to build my test application with g++ command, but it cannot build correctly with the message due to the absence of a function definition. I correctly check the libpci.a file is placed at ./pciutils/local/lib dir and also checked the file defines pci_alloc() function with nm -C libpci.a command, but it fails to build.
$ g++ test.cpp -Ipciutils/local/include/pci -Lpciutils/local/lib -lpci -lz -ludev
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYdhXrN.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `pci_alloc()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

However, when I tried the command with the same command except changing g++ to gcc and
.cpp to .c, it compiles successfully and generate a.out file.
$ gcc test.c -Ipciutils/local/include/pci -Lpciutils/local/lib -lpci -lz -ludev
$ ls
a.out  pciutils  test.c  test.cpp

Now I can go next step for my project, but I want to know what just happened. Why gcc can build, g++ cannot? Is there any difference in terms of finding library adn linking them?
Here is my test.c and test.cpp. Two files are exactly same.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pci.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct pci_access *pacc;
  pacc = pci_alloc();       /* Get the pci_access structure */

  return 0;
}


C and C++ are different languages. If you want to use C header file in a C++ program, you need to make it in a C++ compatible manner. Usually, extern "C" is enough.
#include <cstdio>
extern "C" {
#include <pci.h>
}

int main(void)
{
  struct pci_access *pacc;
  pacc = pci_alloc();       /* Get the pci_access structure */
}


what just happened

Function names not inside extern "C" are name mangled. Research name mangling in C++.

Perfect answer and also thanks to suggestion to research name mangling in C++ :D
